# Automapper: Get list of properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to get a list of properties from nested Object.

That's part of my code:

```
[Table("Articles")]
class Article
{
    public Article()
    {
        ListComplex = new List<ArticlesComplex>();
    }       
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArticlesComplex> ListComplex { get; set; } 
}

[Table("ArticlesComplex")]
class ArticlesComplex
{
    public long ArticleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }    
    public long ComplexId { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Complex { get; set; }
}

//***********************
// DTO
//***********************
public class ArticleDTO
{
    public ArticleDTO()
    {
        ListComplex = new List<long>();
        ListComplexCodes = new List<string>();
    }       
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<long> ListComplex { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ListComplexCodes { get; set; }
}
```

---

**BD**

```
ARTICLES                                    ARTICLESCOMPLEX
Id | Code        | Name     |               ArticleId | ComplexId
 5 | COD_ART_05  | Paper    |                   7     |     5
 6 | COD_ART_06  | Item     |                   7     |     6
 7 | COD_ART_07  | Pendrive |
```

---

Create the mapping:

```
mapper.CreateMap<Article, ArticleDTO>().ForMember(m => m.ListComplex, m =>     m.MapFrom(y => y.ListComplex.Select(x => x.Complex.Id).ToList()))
                                   .ForMember(m => m.ListComplexCodes, m => m.MapFrom(y => y.ListComplex.Select(x => x.Complex.Codigo).ToList()))
```

Finally, I get the result:

```
var dbWhere = DbContext.Articles.Where(x => x.Codigo == "COD_ART_07");
var list = await dbWhere.ProjectTo<ArticleDTO>(null, "ListComplex").ToListAsync();

// list.ListComplex (2) -> 5,6
// list.ListComplexCodes (0) ???
```

I would need to get the property 'Code', in my case "COD_ART_05", "COD_ART_06" in the field 'ListComplexCodes'.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Automapper has nothing to do with this